# Android-dispatchTouchEvent is not catching ACTION_CANCEL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am overriding dispatchTouchEvent() method to detect each and every touch in an activity.

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("android test "+event.toString());
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

But this method is catching only ACTION_UP,ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE events,not ACTION_CANCEL event. What may be the reason for this ?

Comment: because ACTION_CANCEL is not a "real" touch event? ACTION_UP, ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE are directly linked with user's fingers, ACTION_CANCEL is not it is done by calling MotionEvent#cancel()

Comment: any other way we can detect ACTION_CANCEL (not using listener) ?

Comment: what for? why do you need that?

Comment: I want to check all these events ...including ACTION_CANCEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pskink's answer is correct. i.e. ACTION_CANCEL is a system event.

"ACTION_CANCEL occurs when the parent takes possession of the motion, for example when the user has dragged enough across a list view that it will start scrolling instead of letting you press the buttons inside of i.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29